# Codeigniter mysql procedure multiple variables

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, stored-procedures

Ok. We can call MySQL procedures in Codeigniter like this:

```
$buf = array('something', NULL); //array of vars
$this->db->query("CALL some_proc(?, ?)", $buf); //calling stored procedure
```

But if I have huge array (25-30 items), is there a smoother way to call MySQL routine using arrays? Something better than $this->db->query("CALL some_proc(?, ?, ?, ? ...");
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... You can `$this->db->escape()` them before and parse string.

```
$arr_cols = array('value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3');
foreach(array_keys($arr_cols) as $h)
    $arr_cols[$h] = $this->db->escape($arr_cols[$h]);

$str_cols = implode(', ', $arr_cols);

$this->db->query("CALL some_proc({$str_cols})");
```

Comment: @Robin Castlin: I'm getting an array from view( $email_to = $this->input->post('sendMail[]'); ), to controller. oHow I can pass this to stored procedure in model ?

Comment: @GaneshAher Hello, your issue doesn't seem too relevant to this reply. I guess `$email_to` is an array which you'd have to loop through. You didn't give me much to work on here.

Comment: @RobinCastlin will you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092525/how-to-pass-array-as-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-mysql question.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php):

```
$this->db->query("CALL some_proc(?" . str_repeat(",?", count($buf)-1) . ")", $buf);
```

Comment: @skater_nex: So, what's the problem then?  Your accepted solution is no more performant, but a lot more verbose (and relies on the `escape` function to save you from SQL injection, rather than prepared statements which ought to be safer)...

Comment: agreed. I wanted more elegant way. Your solution is perfect (like mine) and it works. But never the less...

Comment: let's say: i wanted alternative solution.